# Re-training (fine tune) specific layers of a pre-trained model (saved as ckpt) in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

I am doing my fist steps in TF and I feel that I am confused...

I am trying to fine tune (retrain) a pre-trained model that I have downloaded from [object detection zoo](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md).
More specifically I want to train only the `BoxPredictor` layers of the [ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco](http://download.tensorflow.org/models/object_detection/ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco_2018_03_29.tar.gz): `BoxEncodingPredictor` (weights+biases) and `ClassPredictor` (weights+biases).

From my understanding I need to do the following steps:

```
var_list = list(filter(box_predictor_filter, tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES)))
loss = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.LOSSES)
optim = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(loss=loss, var_list=var_list)
```

**The problem is that I am unable to get the `var_list` and the `loss` from the graph. in the way I have expected:**

I am importing the "ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco" graph using  `tf.train.import_meta_graph`, like follows:

```
import os
import tensorflow as tf

ckpt_path = os.path.join(MODELS_PATH,"ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco_2018_03_29")

def import_graph_from_ckpt():
    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(os.path.join(ckpt_path, 'model.ckpt.meta'))
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint(ckpt_path))
        graph = tf.get_default_graph()
    return graph
```

But all variables lists are empty:

```
my_graph = import_graph_from_ckpt()
print("------------ *** TRAINABLE_VARIABLES *** ------------")
print(my_graph.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES))
# output: []
```

I also tried different types of variables and all of them are empty.

But `get_operations()` returns variables:

```
print("------------ *** get_operations VariableV2 *** ------------")
graph_vars = list(filter(lambda op: op.type == "VariableV2", my_graph.get_operations()))
print(len(graph_vars))
# output: 345
```

**How can this be? how can I restore the graph with the trainable variables?**